# Java - Checking session and redirecting if doesn't exist

Tags: java, session

Ok, so I basically want to have a session checker where it will request the specific session name attribute and check if exists. If doesn't exists it will then redirect to login page. It sounds simple but I have a problem with redirecting.

When I remove redirect and just print some text under if statements it gets printed on a page. But when I try to redirect, it won't.
The code is under one of the controller files which is included in the beginning of page with

```
<jsp:include page="/radnikSession" />
```

I've written the code which looks like this.

```
String id;

HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
id = (String)session.getAttribute("sessionRadnikID");

if(id == null) {
    //out.println("No session id");
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Be wary that `session` may be null! `getSession` returns the current session; if there is none, null will be returned unless the method is passed `true`, which causes a brand new session to be created and returned. Anyhow, what behavior are you seeing, because what you've provided should work (assuming you aren't running into a NullPointerException).

Comment: You may want to not just check for `null`, but also if it has any content.  I stopped doing `null` checks for strings in almost everything and switched to `StringUtils.isBlank(...)` and `StringUtils.isNotBlank(...)`.  As nasukkin said, you may also wind up with a hidden error if the session is `null`.

Comment: What's the point of passing `false` to `request.getSession()`?  If the request is not part of a session already, then surely you *do* want to create one, right?  Otherwise, where is the login page going to store your session attribute?  And if you pass `true` (or use the other version of `getSession()`) then you don't need to worry about `null` being returned.

Comment: Where exactly are you placing this code?

Comment: @Jonny Henly, yes I checked the value of id and its null.

Comment: We need more info... where is this code executing, and how do you arrive here.  Are you receiving an error anywhere?  You should be doing this in a  filter.

Comment: @el n00b When I remove redirect and just print some text in under if statements it gets printed on a page. But when I try to redirect, it wont

Comment: @slambeth No, I don't receiving any errors. The code is under source packages and included to .jsp page at the very beginning

Comment: Make sure you're not sending back content:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600334/my-response-sendredirect-isnt-working

Comment: That is your problem.  You need to research creating a java filter.  If you're including this in your JSP  A-Shame on you :), B, the server has already sent headers and started responding to the request so it is too late to redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like so:

```
public class SecurityFilter implements Filter
{
    public SecurityFilter()
    { 
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig conf) throws ServletException
    {
    }
    public void destroy()
    {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) {
        String id;

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        id = (String)session.getAttribute("sessionRadnikID");

        if(id == null) {
            //out.println("No session id");
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

Then configure it in your web.xml, something like:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Security Page Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.mystuff.security.SecurityFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Security Page Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I made id to work somehow, thanks to your help. But I'm having different issue about redirecting.

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

How to filter all the page there except the login.jsp. I think you know where I'm heading. All the pages of admin panel are there including login.jsp. And now I'm facing infinity redirection.

Comment: You can do a check on the request object to see if the page request is your login page, or login servlet. You'll want to cast "ServletRequest" to "HttpServletRequest", and make use of getRequestURL and/or getRequestURI to check if the requested URL is your login page, and if so, execute "chain.doFilter(...)" rather than the redirect.

Comment: Here is another example that you could take a look at for ideas on how this is done:  http://cse.csusb.edu/turner/java_web_programming/security/filter/